# checking json value in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

```
var saurabhjson= JSON.stringify(data)
```

above returns this json

```
saurabhjson {"recordId":5555,"Key":"5656"}
```

if print the first array in console it get undefined value

```
console.log("saurabhjson[0].recordId",saurabhjson[0].recordId);
```

i want to do some check like this

```
 if(saurabhjson[0].recordId == 5555) {
            $('#div_ajaxResponse2').text("another success");
        }
```

Comment: why are you converting the JSON to a string? You can access the values from data itself.

Comment: You don't need `JSON.stringify()`, remove it

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy how i can check the data values?

Comment: try to access recordId and Key directly from saurabhJson. Like saurabhjson.recordId

Comment: @satpal how i can check the data values?

Comment: @saurabh `data.recordId`

Comment: @saurabh remove this line `var saurabhjson= JSON.stringify(data)` and simply access the values by `data.recordId`

Comment: @AnkushJain i got this saurabhjson.recordId undefined

Comment: @RGraham `{"recordId":5555,"Key":"5656"}` This is his data format, i dont see any array here. Then why are suggesting `data[0]`?

Comment: @RGraham got thisdata[0]undefined

Comment: @saurabh: There's obviously more going on here than what you're showing us. What is `data`? Is it a JS object, or a string? Should you be doing `JSON.parse()` instead of `JSON.stringify()`? Give us a full example to debug.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy Fixed that already

Comment: thanks all console.log("data.recordId"+data.recordId); WORKS '

Comment: @saurabh, you should mark one of the two correct answers as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the method suggests `JSON.stringify(data)`. It converts a js object to a **jsonstring** now if you want a key out of this string it can't be done before parsing it to json.

So i don't get it why do you need to stringify it.

And another thing is you have a js object not an array of objects. so you need to use this on `data` itself:

```
console.log("data.recordId",data.recordId);
```

Comment: If anyone missed it, OP clarified in a comment on their question that this solution works.

Answer (score 3):

You are probably mixing a few things there.

When you do `var saurabhjson= JSON.stringify(data)`, *that `saurabhjson` variable is a string, not an object*, so you can't access its elements like you are trying to do.

Try accessing `data` directly instead, without using `JSON.stringify()`:
`console.log("data.recordId",data.recordId);`